# X264 Encoder API

Tags: c, video, encoding, h.264, x264

I'm studying the X264 API for encoding images.

So far I've built the X264 library and the following code snippet shows how far I am:

```
  int frame_size;
  x264_t* encoder;
  x264_picture_t pic_in, pic_out;
  x264_param_t x264Param;
  int fps = 20;
  int width = 1280;
  int height = 720;
  x264_nal_t* nals;
  int i_nals;

  x264_param_default_preset(&x264Param, "veryfast", "zerolatency");
  x264Param.i_threads = 1;
  x264Param.i_width = 1280;
  x264Param.i_height = 720;
  x264Param.i_fps_num = fps;
  x264Param.i_fps_den = 1;
  x264Param.i_keyint_max = fps;
  x264Param.b_intra_refresh = 1;
  x264Param.rc.i_rc_method = X264_RC_CRF;
  x264Param.rc.f_rf_constant = 25;
  x264Param.rc.f_rf_constant_max = 35;
  x264Param.b_repeat_headers = 1;
  x264Param.b_annexb = 1;
  x264_param_apply_profile(&x264Param, "baseline");

  encoder = x264_encoder_open(&x264Param);

  x264_picture_alloc(&pic_in, X264_CSP_BGR, width, height);

  /* How to fill in bitmap data? */

  frame_size = x264_encoder_encode(encoder, &nals, &i_nals, &pic_in, &pic_out);
  if (frame_size >= 0)
  {
      printf("OK\n");
  }
```

So I'm trying to encode a 24bit BGR bitmap image. However, the x264 header file doesn't show any API function for writing the bitmap image to the encoder. How is this done?

**EDIT**

This code snippet seems to work. I would appreciate a review and some comments. Thanks.

```
  int frame_size;
  int accum_frame_size;
  x264_t* encoder;
  x264_picture_t pic_in, pic_out;
  x264_param_t x264Param;
  int fps = 20;
  int width = 1280;
  int height = 720;
  x264_nal_t* nals;
  int i_nals;
  int64_t frameCount = 0;
  int k;

  for (k = 0; k < (1280*3*720); k++)
  {
     bgr[k] = rand();
  }

  x264_param_default_preset(&x264Param, "veryfast", "zerolatency");
  x264Param.i_threads = 1;
  x264Param.i_width = 1280;
  x264Param.i_height = 720;
  x264Param.i_fps_num = fps;
  x264Param.i_fps_den = 1;
  x264Param.i_keyint_max = fps;
  x264Param.b_intra_refresh = 1;
  x264Param.rc.i_rc_method = X264_RC_CRF;
  x264Param.i_csp = X264_CSP_BGR;
  x264Param.rc.f_rf_constant = 25;
  x264Param.rc.f_rf_constant_max = 35;
  x264Param.b_repeat_headers = 1;
  x264Param.b_annexb = 1;
  x264_param_apply_profile(&x264Param, "baseline");

  encoder = x264_encoder_open(&x264Param);

  x264_picture_alloc(&pic_in, X264_CSP_BGR, width, height);

  /* Load 24-bit BGR bitmap */
  pic_in.img.i_csp = X264_CSP_BGR;
  pic_in.img.i_plane = 1;
  pic_in.img.i_stride[0] = 3 * 1280;
  pic_in.img.plane[0] = bgr;
  pic_in.i_pts = frameCount;
  pic_in.i_type = X264_TYPE_AUTO;
  pic_out.i_pts = frameCount;

  /* Returns a frame size of 912 for first frame in this case */
  frame_size = x264_encoder_encode(encoder, &nals, &i_nals, &pic_in, &pic_out);

  printf("Decoder returned frame size = %d \n", frame_size);
  printf("Decoder returned %d NAL units \n", i_nals);
  if (frame_size >= 0)
  {
     int i;
     int j;


     accum_frame_size = 0;
     for (i = 0; i < i_nals; i++)
     {
        printf("******************* NAL %d (%d bytes) *******************\n", i, nals[i].i_payload);
        for (j = 0; j < nals[i].i_payload; j++)
        {
           if (j == 0) printf("First 10 bytes: ");
           if (j < 10) printf("%02X |", nals[i].p_payload[j]);
           accum_frame_size++;
        }
        printf("\n");

     }
  }

  printf("Verified frame size = %d \n", accum_frame_size);
```

**EDIT #2** 
The encoder outputs this:

```
     x264 [error]: baseline profile doesn't support 4:4:4
     x264 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
     x264 [info]: profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.1, 4:4:4 8-bit
     Decoder returned frame size = 1467194
     Decoder returned 4 NAL units
     ******************* NAL 0 (31 bytes) *******************
     First 10 bytes: 00 |00 |00 |01 |67 |F4 |00 |1F |91 |89 |
     ******************* NAL 1 (8 bytes) *******************
     First 10 bytes: 00 |00 |00 |01 |68 |EF |1F |2C |
     ******************* NAL 2 (595 bytes) *******************
     First 10 bytes: 00 |00 |01 |06 |05 |FF |FF |4C |DC |45 |
     ******************* NAL 3 (1466560 bytes) *******************
     First 10 bytes: 00 |00 |01 |65 |88 |82 |0A |FF |F5 |B0 |
     Verified frame size = 1467194
```

Isn't each NAL unit supposed to start with 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 ?

**szatmary** : I appreciate your valuable feedback. So you're saying that each NAL unit does not necessarily start with 0,0,0,1. However, I'm a bit unclear on your answer. Are you implying that with a certain configuration the NAL units *will* start with 0,0,0,1 ? If so, which configuration is that? I need to make sure that each NAL unit I transmit out on the network to a remote receiver starts with 0,0,0,1. Prior to exploring the x264 library I was using the x264 exe and piped BMP data in and encoded data out from the x264 process. I then parsed the encoder output and looked for NAL units by looking for 0,0,0,1. How do I accomplish the same with the x264 library?

Regarding libswscale:

I downloaded the ffmpeg source and ran configure and make in MINGW. After the process had completed I couldn't find anything but a number of .exe files. How do I build actual static libraries (.lib) which I can use in a Visual Studio project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x264 can not encode BGR. You must convert the image to YUV 4:2:0p. I recommend using libswscale from the ffmpeg project to perform this operation.

EDIT #2

No, a startcode is at least two 0x00 bytes followed by a 0x01. But it can have any number (But is usually two or three null bytes) The 4 byte version is used for detecting byte alighnemnt in serial transmissions and generally precedes SPS and PPS NALUs.

Comment: How do you explain that the x264.exe is able to take raw BGR or RGB bitmap data as input then? And what about the x264 parameter 'X264_CSP_BGR' ? What is that then?

Comment: The x264 executable adds additional functionality. It uses libswscale from ffmpeg to scale (just look at the source)

Comment: So you're saying that I need an extra static library besides the x264 encoder library? Is there a guide somewhere on how to build a static library which contains the libswscale APIs for converting BGR to YUV ?

Comment: Look here: http://www.szatmary.org/blog/25. Also if you have a separate question (how to compile libswscale) you should open a new question.

Comment: szatmary: Any comments on this article? It states that x264 does accept RGB as input. http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=163518